# Content autocomplete in spring tool suite 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-tools-4

The autocomplete for content is not working in spring tool suite 4. I have checked the settings

[image: Content Assist dialog]

Could anyone tell me how to solve this.

For Example:

if I enter Math. -> and press ctrl + space for suggestions it show no default templates.

Answer (score 26):

In the **Auto Activation** section fill in **Auto activation triggers** for Java:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ._
```

[image]